# Using javascript to record reaction time in qualtrics using keypress without advancing

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I am new to javascript and learning how to use it within qualtrics. In my survey, I have a question that is set to display for 1500 ms to which respondents must press one of two keys ('S' or 'D') to make their response. What I would like is for Qualtrics to record how long it took respondents to strike one of these keys before it advances to the next question and for Qualtrics to not advance automatically to the next question after keypress.

The code below allows responses using either the 'S' or 'D' key and prevents the question from advancing automatically after keypress. However, the reaction time recorded is always duration of the question (1500 ms) as opposed to how long it took participants to respond. If anyone has any ideas on how I can accurately record reaction time to keypress it would be much appreciated!

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function () {
  this.hideNextButton();
  this.hidePreviousButton();
  var that = this;
  Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
    var choiceID = null;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 83: // 'S' was pressed
        choiceID = 1;
        break;
      case 68: // 'D' was pressed
        choiceID = 2;
        break;
    }
    if (choiceID) {
      Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
      that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm on my phone so I can't type it out. But basically you use a new DateTime() on the onload. Then on if choice id you create another DateTime and subtract the first one. If I remember correctly you use getTime() on both and you subtract you keep the ms time difference.

Comment: @Jørgen - thanks! I've tried to include this, but it still doesn't seem to be working. I think the problem is that it's not writing the reaction time to my datafile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try with following code:

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function () {
  let timeOnLoad = new Date().getTime();
  this.hideNextButton();
  this.hidePreviousButton();
  var that = this;
  Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
    var choiceID = null;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 83: // 'S' was pressed
        choiceID = 1;
        break;
      case 68: // 'D' was pressed
        choiceID = 2;
        break;
    }
    if (choiceID) {
      let timeTaken = new Date().getTime() - timeOnLoad;
      console.log(timeTaken);
      Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
      that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
    }
  });
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, @jasmin_makasana! I tried the code! The responses are still being recorded, but it still doesn't seem to be recording the time to first keypress. The only reaction time I have is the duration that the question is presented to respondents (1500 ms).

Comment: @jasmine_makasana - okay, so I see that the reaction times are being written to my browser's console. Do you happen to know how I can extract this information and have it written to my qualtrics datafile?

Comment: @SaraGallant, Sorry, I don't know about that.

Comment: @jasmin_makasana nice answer :)

Answer (score 0):

From taking a look at the documentation, I guess this would do the trick.

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function () {
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  this.hideNextButton();
  this.hidePreviousButton();
  var that = this;
  Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
    var choiceID = null;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 83: // 'S' was pressed
        choiceID = 1;
        break;
      case 68: // 'D' was pressed
        choiceID = 2;
        break;
    }
    if (choiceID) {
      let reactionTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
      Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
      that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
      that.setEmbeddedData('reactionTime', reactionTime);
    }
  });
});
```

reference: https://s.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/QuestionAPI/classes/Qualtrics%20JavaScript%20Question%20API.html